# how to use golang regex all match within string

Tags: regex, go

How do i match all the substrin within the text. I have the code below. however, the result is just the same text again. I am expecting something like

["59-1124043-1057 - SIDE RAIL1PC15-Feb-2020", ..., "59-1124043-1317 - BRAKE RAIL2PC15-Feb-2020"]

Please help.

```
PNExprV2 = `[^(-138)][\d]+-.*[\d][\s]+.*[\d]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2}[\d]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[\d]{4}`

text := "59-1124043-1053 - FLOATING JOINT4PC15-Feb-2020 Purchase PriceUSD 28.00112.00per 1 PCTaxable:  N    Resale:  N<70.000KG DHL Express - Intl Shpts 962183650SCAC1:DHLCOver70.000KG Agility Logistics - Export StandardSCAC2:AGYC3 59-1124043-1055 - UNDER RAIL1PC15-Feb-2020 Purchase PriceUSD 138.00138.00per 1 PCTaxable:  N    Resale:  N<70.000KG DHL Express - Intl Shpts 962183650SCAC1:DHLCOver70.000KG Agility Logistics - Export StandardSCAC2:AGYC4 59-1124043-1056 - UPPER RAIL1PC15-Feb-2020"

PNParser := regexp.MustCompile(PNExprV2)

line1 := PNParser.FindAllStringSubmatch(c, -1)
```

Comment: The text you expect is not part of the text! Please update.

Comment: @PoulBak They are the start and end of the text.

Comment: In regex, you can't match something, then skip some characters and match something again. What you can do is create groups with what you want, then use these groups.